How do you know if the interview candidate wouldn't betray you?
Our work sometimes handles a lot of sensitive information. And we often do things a little wild. I don’t want to see that one day our employees come against or betray the company or me. How do I select people who are quite hard worker and loyal to the company?

Clarify what you mean by, "we often do things a little wild"?

"Often we do things a little wild". Could you elaborate on that? It's not the sort of thing we want to hear from someone who handles a lot of sensitive information.

Loyalty between employer and employee used to work both ways.  But, over the last few decades, it's faded to almost nothing.  Companies rarely hesitate over staff redundancies (as we've seen recently) and workers move jobs pretty regularly.  To be honest, most employer-employee relationships are based on money and quality of life these days.

It's a job, not national security.  "All debts are settled on payday" is a good way to look at it, stop expecting people to be loyal unless you have proven the company is that way first.

You're solving the wrong problem.
I'm not quite sure what you mean by "come against" or "betray" the company, but taking the charitable interpretation of "misuse the confidental information they had access to during their employment", the best way by far to prevent that is to treat them well so they don't want to misuse that information - i.e. this is a you problem, not a them problem.

This is what non-disclosure agreements or NDAs are for.

And we often do things a little wild.

But NDAs do not cover illegal activity, if that's what you are getting at.
Otherwise, they should suffice for both interview candidates and full time employees for anything related to your company's finances, business, clients, intellectual property, engineering practices, and day-to-day stuff.

"How do I select people who are hard worker[s] and loyal?" If I had a once-sentence answer to that, I'd start my own recruiting firm or write a book and be rich and famous. Every employer struggles with this problem. There is no easy answer. It's not like you can magically determine that an applicant will be hard-working and loyal if you just ask the right question or look for the right subtle clue in body language or whatever. Or at least, if there is some magic way to find out, know one knows what it is.
As others have said, you can require employees to sign a Non-Disclosure Agreement. This doesn't guarantee they won't give away company secrets, of course, but it would at least give you a legal right to sue.
If by "sensitive information" you mean government secrets, weapon designs or some such, than if someone reveals unauthorized information he is subject to criminal prosecution. The government will take care of it, not your problem. But if you mean trade secrets, then yeah, it's your problem.
You can limit who has access to trade secrets. Like, Kentucky Fried Chicken relies heavily on a secret recipe. They keep it secret by having only a tiny number of employees know the full recipe. Others are given half the recipe, they mix up a batch of herbs and spices, and then they mix the two batches together. I wonder how they keep people in the two groups from talking to each other and sharing the recipe, but maybe they rely on NDAs and personal integrity for that.
On the other hand, I used to work for a database design company that boasted they had a superior methodology for designing databases. It was so secret that only two employees knew it. So ... how were the rest of us supposed to implement this design methodology? We weren't allowed to even know what it was, but the company boasted we would apply it to design projects. I have no idea if it was even a particularly good methodology, as I wasn't one of the ones allowed to see it. All seemed pretty silly to me.

3 things.

background check.

This should be self explanatory.

Good Compensation/Treatment

Employees are much like you. Much as you wouldn't stay/be loyal if you weren't being paid well. This means that your wages need to be competitive. One thing that is really important. Don't pay new hires more than old hands. Also, promote internally. If your managers/higherups are external hires, then your internal employees will go elsewhere for career advancement.
Additionally a good amount of PTO helps. As does sick leave, bereavement leave, paternity/maternity/Family medical leave.
People are loyal to companies that are loyal to them. The main way that companies show their loyalty to employees is by compensating them well, and by not screwing them over come promotion time. Especially important don't not promote someone because they are "indispensable" where they are at right now... Also don't force someone to take a promotion they don't want.

Good managers / employees

Self explanatory but your managers are the people that your new hires interact with. If your managers treat them well. They will become loyal to the manager/company. If your managers treat them badly they will leave.
Same goes with other employees. Don't tolerate employees that mistreat their co-workers. It doesn't matter what level of specialized knowledge/how hard to replace that employee is. Anyone who generates a toxic work-environment causes negative productivity in everyone who is forced to interact with them. This increases your turnover and decrees employee loyalty.
